# Batching the bulk updates of millions of rows with peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, peewee

- I have an SQLite3 database with a table that has twenty million rows.
- I would like to update the values of some of the columns in the table (for all rows).
- I am running into performance issues (about only 1'000 rows processed per second).
- I would like to continue using the `peewee` module in python to interact with the
  database.

So I'm not sure if I am taking the right approach with my code. After trying some ideas that all failed, I attempted to perform the update in batches. My first solution here was to iterate in over the cursor with `islice` as so:

```
import math, itertools
from tqdm import tqdm
from cool_project.database import db, MyTable

def update_row(row):
    row.column_a = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_b = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_c = computation(row.column_d)

fields = (MyTable.column_a
          MyTable.column_b
          MyTable.column_c)

rows = MyTable.select()
total_rows = rows.count()
page_size = 1000
total_pages = math.ceil(total_rows / page_size)
# Start #
with db.atomic():
    for page_num in tqdm(range(total_pages)):
        page = list(itertools.islice(rows, page_size))
        for row in page: update_row(row)
        MyTable.bulk_update(page, fields=fields)
```

This failed, because it would attempt to put the result of the whole query into memory. So I adapted the code to use the `paginate` function.

```
import math
from tqdm import tqdm
from cool_project.database import db, MyTable

def update_row(row):
    row.column_a = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_b = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_c = computation(row.column_d)

fields = (MyTable.column_a
          MyTable.column_b
          MyTable.column_c)

rows = MyTable.select()
total_rows = rows.count()
page_size = 1000
total_pages = math.ceil(total_rows / page_size)
# Start #
with db.atomic():
    for page_num in tqdm(range(1, total_pages+1)):
        # Get a batch #
        page = MyTable.select().paginate(page_num, page_size)
        # Update #
        for row in page: update_row(row)
        # Commit #
        MyTable.bulk_update(page, fields=fields)
```

But it's still quite slow, and would take >24 hours to complete.

What is strange is that the speed (in number of rows per second) notably decreases as time goes by. The scripts starts with ~1000 rows per second. But after half an hour it's down to 250 rows per second.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issues are twofold -- you are pulling all results into memory and you are using the bulk update API, which is quite complex/special and which is also completely unnecessary for SQLite.

Try the following:

```
def update_row(row):
    row.column_a = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_b = computation(row.column_d)
    row.column_c = computation(row.column_d)

fields = (MyTable.column_a
          MyTable.column_b
          MyTable.column_c)

rows = MyTable.select()
with db.atomic():
    for row in rows.iterator():  # Add ".iterator()" to avoid caching rows
        update_row(row)
        row.save(only=fields)
```